# Apache2 sites-enabled Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may

Tags: apache2

Upgraded my Apache2 server and now cannot start the server.
Iam receiving an error for the following configuration
**"Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may."**

For the following command.
**Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews**

Please let me know what is wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To rephrase the error message: You gave multiple arguments to the "Options" directive, but you used a mix of things starting with +/- and things NOT starting with +/-.

It's no longer accepted that way in 2.4 because it's not doing what you intend many times and can lead to inadvertent options being enabled.

Your 3 argument directive is equivalent to just

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```